# Is it possible to add a file to my app platform in digital ocean

Tags: digital-ocean, paas

I have my static content-based app (DigitalOcean App Platform) up and running. I’d like to add one file which contains a certificate through which it can connect to MongoDB. Is it possible to add the file without adding it to my Github repo?

Answer (score 0):

Since certificates are generally small, I would add the certificate to the source files you already have. Your Mongo client can then use this to connect. Doing this Keeps your app Simple and Stupid.